# Backbone model attribute

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone Model that basically looks like this:

```
 var User = Backbone.Model.extend({


            idAttribute: "_id",

            givenName: 'UserModel',

            urlRoot: '/users',

            defaults: {
                firstName: null,
                lastName: null,
                username: null,
                password: null,
                email: null
            },

            initialize: function (options) {

                this.options = options || {};

                _.bindAll(this, 'deleteModel', 'persist', 'validate');


            },

            constructor: function (attributes, options) {
                Backbone.Model.apply(this, arguments);
            },

            validate: function (attr) {

                return undefined;
            },


            persist: function (adds, callback) {

            },
            deleteModel: function (callback) {


            }

        });
```

but then why doesn't givenName show up in the debugger? I assume it's something to do with the nature of Backbone and nothing that's wrong with my code or the debugger.

[image]

here I even console.logged "model.givenName" and it is indeed defined. So I don't understand how Backbone is working:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/h61xpl8st98wcqi/Screenshot%202015-07-07%2020.57.49.png?dl=0

[image]

Comment: The things in the `extend` call go on the prototype. This is just how JavaScript handles inheritance without classes, nothing to do with Backbone specifically.

Comment: seems strange. why wouldn't the predefined properties go on the prototype and the newly defined properties go at the object level? seems backwards. also, my personally defined functions (persist and deleteModel) show up, but the plain value (givenName) does not. Can you explain that? Doesn't gel with what you just said.

Comment: Look into how `_.bindAll` works.

Comment: ok cool, I see, would you recommend somehow putting a loop for bindAll? it feels weird to put string literals as arguments to that function. for all my backbone components it would be cool to just loop and bindAll top level properties

Comment: `_.bindAll` needs the function *names* so that it can replace them with bound versions, those bound versions of course have to be on the instance rather than the prototype since they are specific to each instance. `_.bindAll` is rarely needed anyway, the functions are almost always fine in the prototype.

Comment: I think this is a shortcoming of backbone, it should be able to take the function references themselves, not just the name of the function. with just the names as string literals an IDE can't help you correct mistakes. var func = incoming.bind(whatever); return func. it's not hard.

Comment: (1) `_.bindAll` is rarely needed so who cares? (2) Why are you binding those functions at all? (3) Have you looked into how exactly `_.bindAll` works? How would it know what something's name is if you didn't tell it?

Comment: Backbone takes the string literal and goes and finds the function with the same name. I am sure it could use the function reference and go and find that same function also...at least I hope JS is capable of that

Comment: Don't hope, go and try to implement it yourself. After all, "it's not hard". I still don't know why you think you need to use `_.bindAll` at all.

Comment: I am using _.bindAll simply because I have only been using JS for 8 months and don't know the ins and outs of the language and thus Backbone. One possibility, is that Backbone binds prexisting/predefined properties to 'this', but that I have to bind my own defined properties myself. I simply am not 100% sure about this so I just use _.bindAll to ensure this for now. It would be reasonable to assume what I just said was true. I'd have to know more about _.extend and it's variants as well as the Backbone source to know for sure if this were true or false.

Comment: Frankly, Backbone is not great, but it's more because JS is not great. For example, copying and moving around attributes, options and attaching them to 'this' willy nilly. But only doing it for models and not views and collections. It's crap.

Comment: And, for example, if you pass options to a View, but an options property is not a predefined property, it won't get copied to 'this'. Backbone turns something that could be "just works" into "look at the source every 10 minutes" until you're an expert with 2+ years experience. but again static typing would help because then at least I would know what arguments a predefined function accepts and returns.

Comment: No, that's not a reasonable assumption in JavaScript. You think it is crap because you're thinking in some other language and assuming that JavaScript behaves that way; program JavaScript in JavaScript, Java in Java, C in C, trying to program X in Y just makes a big mess (look at the way most people attempt to use SQL for examples). `this` inside a JavaScript function almost always depends on how the function is called rather than where it is defined, that's just how the tool works. Your proposed `options` behavior is a recipe for confusion when things change.

Comment: btw I mean this in the most polite way possible - just because I don't understand the tool, doesn't mean it's not crap. for example, most OSS is crap. people get mad if I criticize it because it's almost always free. "it was free to you, you should appreciate it." it doesn't matter whether it's free or not, it's still crap. I like Node.js and I think JS is good, at least its event driven single threaded model is totally solid.

Comment: But there are a lot of things about JS that make using JS APIs difficult, because function signatures don't really exist. You are instantly making APIs 5x harder to use because you have to look at the source all the time instead of having the function signatures right there in the codebase. It's an obvious point that you must accept.

Comment: I know I am lucky to have entered front-end development now, instead of a couple years ago when there was even worse cross-browser compatibility and fewer standards.  Backbone is not great, but I don't think other front-end frameworks are much better for a front-end newb. This is because they all have to work with the DOM and JS. JS is indefensible as a language, and has caused a lot of people a lot of pain over the last 20 years. With a tool that's so maleable, a lot of crap and unpredictable code can be written. Like Perl or the like.

Comment: mu i'd be interested if you think this is a good or bad or impossible idea: https://www.quora.com/Could-JavaScript-implement-this-new-keyword